# What is the relation between windows services and .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I've studied Windows Services and .Net framework.
From my research, a windows service is a type of application that is primarily used to run in background and can be done automatically or periodically. And 
.Net is a software framework developed by Microsoft that runs primarily on Microsoft Windows.

What I would like to know where in the stack of the .Net framework are basically the windows services, supposing windows services use .Net framework.
Any further exaplanation on the relation between these two will be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two completely separate notions. They're related in the way that, for example, a hotel janitorial staff might be related to a guest of the hotel. Just because they reside in the same "building" at some point, doesn't mean there is any "useful" (i.e. substantive for the purposes of comparison given the context) relationship between them, though their paths may cross for whatever reason. The same goes for the notion of windows services and the .NET framework.

Windows services can be written in many languages, including .NET languages.  .NET itself has a built-in project template for creating a Windows service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like your comparation.

Answer (score 1):

based on your post:

> "windows service is a type of application that is primarily used to
>   run in background and can be done automatically or periodically"

that is correct, as others mentioned above, you can use any framework to build those services.

Regarding the second portion of your question:

> " .Net is a software framework developed by Microsoft that runs
>   primarily on Microsoft Windows"

Is exactly that, a framework, you can use this framework to create the above mentioned services.

A windows service is just an application that runs without user interaction, .NET is a set of tools you can use to build such applications.

You already have the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A service does not have to be written in .NET, anything will do.  Two basic things need to happen.  First of all, the Service Manager built into Windows needs to know that the service exists.  That requires writing a handful of registry keys.  Bare essentials are the service name, where the EXE is located and how it should be started.  The ServiceInstaller class you write takes care of that, you run InstallUtil.exe to let that installer do its job.  Have a look-see with Regedit.exe, navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services key.

And then the program needs to use a winapi function to talk to the service manager.  So that the manager can deliver notifications that tell service to start, stop, pause, etc.  That's wrapped by the ServiceBase class, you get friendly methods you can override.  Like OnStart(), etc.

That's all there is to it.  The service manager takes care of the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

A windows service is a type of application that has been around a long time before .NET.

You can write a Windows Service in many programming languages. You can write a Windows Service in .NET and a language making use of it (C#, VB.NET, etc) but that is not required. You can also use other languages that do not use the .NET framework to write a Windows Service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So just to confirm, when I create a project of Windows Service with Visual Studio (2012 for instance) for visual c#, im creating a windows service in .NET?